# Creating a SQL totals table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

What I am trying to accomplish is a SQL table that contains several different totals based off of 5 other tables. This would be so that when my application needs those totals, it would not need to perform the sum since it is a rather large query.

I would like to know if there is a recommended method to have a totals table that constantly updates based on changes made in other tables. I have thought of replacing it with an indexed view or having triggers on each of the tables that are being summed, but it seems inefficient to rerun the sum query every time a field is updated. One other thing I thought of would be to have a trigger on update and every time the data changes, I would just add or remove the difference from the stored total. My end goal is to have some totals that are constantly up to date.

The table is showing totals per product. (e.g. total qty from table1 + total qty from table2)

If this is too general, I can give more specifics about table structure.

Comment: I think you need to look into triggers.

Comment: @GordonLinoff So something along the lines of a trigger that just increments up or down may be better than an indexed view?

Comment: Triggers or indexed views, all depends on complexity. You may encounter excessive locking on the table with total values. Other option would be to write stored procedures to do update on detailed table and totals table. I would say you need to test all available options for performance and stability.

Comment: Two techniques I've used for websites that can tolerate somewhat stale data, e.g. a few minutes old, that is needed frequently, but is somewhat slow to generate: (1) Use a scheduled job, e.g. with Server Agent, to update a cache table at a regular interval. The cache can have multiple results so that there is always a complete set available. The task deletes the prior results after completing the new set. (2) Keep a cache table with a timestamp. When a request is made check the timestamp. If it is too stale then the current user pays the price (several seconds) to update the cached data.

Comment: @Quark . . . An trigger is going to keep the data as valid as the most recent committed transactions.  There might be some more overhead when querying a materialized view to get the latest results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up putting these in a queue when the underlying data was changed, and using a scheduled task to update the totals at a regular interval. We decided the tradeoff in data freshness was worth not having to recalculate the total with every transaction.

Answer (score 0):

Add a trigger to tables in question and check for the only the relevant value changing rather than run the sum each time a field that is irrelevant to the total on the computed table is modified.